# How can I open a div alternating using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, tap, jquery-events

I have written this code:

```
$(".tiptext").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".description").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".description").hide();
});
```

It works fine, at least on a PC. For touchscreen I am looking for a solution, where I only change the js file. I am looking for some code that alternately opens and closes the box. This works well to open the box:

```
$(".tiptext").on('tap', function () {
$(this).children(".description").show();
```

But to open and close the box alternately, closing it with the second fingertouch, and open it again with the third fingertouch, and so on, this is not working:

```
$(".tiptext").on('tap', function () {
    $(this).children(".description").show();
}).on('tap', function () {
    $(this).children(".description").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.toggle()`

```
$(".tiptext").on("tap", function () {
    $(this).children(".description").toggle();
})
```

Comment: Great help! Thank you very much! Toggle works! I knew this syntax, but haven't the idea to use it. There is one more thing: Using your code, the div is shown first and hides on.tap. But I want it the other way round, that it is first hidden and shows up on the tap.

Comment: Everything is fine! I had to put the css also in another file and now the box is hidden first.